# how I can get method value from parent class? I get an error while running this code

Tags: python

```
class V_Tangensial():
    pi = 3.14

    def __init__(self, n=1480, db=220):
        self.n = n
        self.db = db

    def v_tangensial(self):
        v = (self.pi * self.n * self.db) / 60000
        self.v += v
        print(f"Kecepatan Tangensial = {v}")

class Kd(V_Tangensial):

    def __init__(self, yh=1, yg=1.5, ys=0.9, ko=0.33, yv=0, kd=0):
        v = super(Kd, self).v_tangensial(self)

    def Nilai_KD(self):
        yv = 0.7 + (0.6/(1+(8/v)**2))
```

Comment: When you call *super()*, you don't have to specify *self*.

Comment: From this line *v = super(Kd, self).v_tangensial(self)*, the variable is *kd* and not *Kd*.

Comment: Actually I need v value from v_tangensial method in parent class, so I can put it in Nilai_KD method in child method. How I can implement it?

Comment: Why does `Kd` inherit from `V_Tangensial` when the two classes seem entirely unrelated, and why is `Kd` a class at al when its only non-`__init__` method doesn't use `self`?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `super().__init__` call. Once you do it `v_tangensial` will be in `Kd` instance, i.e. `self`

```
class V_Tangensial():
    pi = 3.14

    def __init__(self, n=1480, db=220):
        self.n = n
        self.db = db
        self.v = 0

    def v_tangensial(self):
        v = (self.pi * self.n * self.db) / 60000
        self.v += v
        print(f"Kecepatan Tangensial = {v}")


class Kd(V_Tangensial):

    def __init__(self, yh=1, yg=1.5, ys=0.9, ko=0.33, yv=0, kd=0):
        super().__init__(kd)
        self.v_tangensial()

    def Nilai_KD(self):
        yv = 0.7 + (0.6/(1+(8/self.v)**2))
```

Comment: I need value from v_tangensial method to input in Nilai_KD method in child class

Comment: @DeBujos `v` is part of the instance, you can get it with `self.v` in `Nilai_KD`.

Comment: Can you please fix my program? I really confused

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Comment: @DeBujos change `self.v = None` to `self.v = 0`

Comment: it's can't bro, v value in Nilai_KD method become zero

Comment: @DeBujos Because you initialize `self.n` to 0 when you pass `kd` to `super().__init__(kd)`. Either don't use it `super().__init__()` or set value other than 0. `Kd(kd=2).Nilai_KD()`.